# Android add JSON to <string>

Tags: android, json, listview

I want to add json to listview,

but I have no idea

I list items with listview like that;

```
public class ListSectionActivity extends Activity {

    private AndroidListAdapter list_adapter;
    private ListView lv_android;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_section);

        DataCollection.data_arr=new ArrayList<DataCollection>();

        DataCollection.data_arr.add(new DataCollection("apple"));
        DataCollection.data_arr.add(new DataCollection("car"));


        lv_android=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_android);

        list_adapter=new AndroidListAdapter(ListSectionActivity.this, R.layout.list_item,DataCollection.data_arr);


        ListSeparateAdapter<DataCollection> listsectionAdapter = new ListSeparateAdapter<DataCollection>(ListSectionActivity.this,
                list_adapter, R.layout.enroll_section_list, R.id.tv_section);

        lv_android.setAdapter(listsectionAdapter);

    }

}
```

but I want to list item from json.
my json code:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
                JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("main");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray server = c.getJSONArray("home");
                    for(int j=0; j<server.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject serverObject = server.getJSONObject(j);

                                   string rank = serverObject.getString("rank");


                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

my json;

```
{
  "main":[
    {
      "home":[
        {"rank":"33"},
        {"rank":"72"},
        {"rank":"49"}
      ]
    }   
  ]
}
```

I want to add "string rank" to my listview.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Edit: I could add json to listview but I can only list first json item. my new code

```
public class ListSectionActivity extends Activity {

    private AndroidListAdapter list_adapter;
    private ListView lv_android;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_section);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ReadJSON().execute("url");
            }
        });
    }

    class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return readURL(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
                JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("main");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray server = c.getJSONArray("home");
                    for(int j=0; j<server.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject serverObject = server.getJSONObject(j);


                        String rank = serverObject.getString("rank");

                        DataCollection.data_arr=new ArrayList<DataCollection>();
                        DataCollection.data_arr.add(new DataCollection(rank));
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            lv_android=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_android);

            list_adapter=new AndroidListAdapter(ListSectionActivity.this, R.layout.list_item,DataCollection.data_arr);

            ListSeparateAdapter<DataCollection> listsectionAdapter = new ListSeparateAdapter<DataCollection>(ListSectionActivity.this,
                    list_adapter, R.layout.enroll_section_list, R.id.tv_section);

            lv_android.setAdapter(listsectionAdapter);
        }
    }


    private static String readURL(String theUrl) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {

            URL url = new URL(theUrl);

            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }

}
```

DataCollection

```
public class DataCollection {
    public String name;

    public static ArrayList<DataCollection> data_arr=null;
    public DataCollection(String name){


        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Comment: post json also here

Comment: I have added json @quicklearner

Comment: make  DataCollection.data_arr global , not inside oncreate, so you can directly add in data_arr  if on post execute is in same class or if it is in different send a reference of data_arr  in to asynctask so it can change from there.

Comment: Hi Amit Sinha, I have updated my post. please check it. Thank you @AmitSinha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: You can do this inside your onPostexecute. Save the rank array inside a listview and use it inside your adapter.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
  DataCollection.data_arr=new ArrayList<DataCollection>();
    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
        JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("main");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray server = c.getJSONArray("home");
            for(int j=0; j<server.length(); j++){
                JSONObject serverObject = server.getJSONObject(j);

                String rank = serverObject.getString("rank");

                    DataCollection.data_arr.add(new DataCollection(rank));


            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(!data_arr.isEmpty()){

        //you can set the adapter and listview here. Something like this
        your_list_adapter=new AndroidListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item,data_arr);

        your_lv_android.setAdapter(list_adapter);


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I have updated my post. please check it. Thank you

Comment: ok. what does DataCollection class look like? Also what do you want to display in every row of your listview?

Comment: I added DataCollection to post. I want to display all rank in listview but I can only display first rank.

Comment: I have edited my answer . You were declaring   DataCollection.data_arr=new ArrayList<DataCollection>(); inside the for loop which was overwriting and creating new arrayobject each time